# itext: Textextracting example not working

Tags: itext

I want to extract text from an PDF document page wise and I am using itext. I used the example code from their [website](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-15):

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pathToFile);
PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
TextExtractionStrategy strategy = parser.processContent(page, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
```

The method `processContent` gives me a `NullPointerException`. What did I do wrong?

This is the stacktrace I get when using version 5.5.0 with [this](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=04085076377229572360) file:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser.processContent(PdfReaderContentParser.java:82)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser.processContent(PdfReaderContentParser.java:105)
at org.languageresources.PDFExtraktor.extractTextFromPage(PDFExtractor.java:100)
```

Comment: Don't expect an answer to this question without sharing more information. The code on the web site works for us with iText 5.5.9 and the test files. Which version are you using? Which PDF are you trying to parse? Without an answer to these two questions, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I added information about the stacktrace, the file and the version I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the code sniplet and sample document you gave I tried to reproduce the issue but to no avail, text extraction worked fine.

Furthermore, the stacktrace given:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser.processContent(PdfReaderContentParser.java:82)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser.processContent(PdfReaderContentParser.java:105)
at org.languageresources.PDFExtraktor.extractTextFromPage(PDFExtractor.java:100)
```

does not match the alleged version 5.5.0 because `PdfReaderContentParser.java:82` in that version is an empty line and `PdfReaderContentParser.java:105` does not exist: Back then that file was only 85 lines in size.

---

Assuming, though, that you use the current version 5.5.9, the stacktrace makes sense, in that version `PdfReaderContentParser.java:82` is the second of these lines:

```
PdfDictionary pageDic = reader.getPageN(pageNumber);
PdfDictionary resourcesDic = pageDic.getAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);
```

and `pageDic` indeed can be `null` if there is no page `pageNumber`.

Thus, please check that `page`, the page number in question, is between 1 and `reader.getNumberOfPages()` inclusive.

Comment: You were right about two tings: I'm using version 5.5.9 (sorry for the typo) and my page number was not between 1 and the max number of pages. I assumed the numbers start at 0. Thanks a lot!